# CCnet editing Report Email

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I would like to edit the "header.xsl" file in the /xls folder, does anybody know where I can find the correspondending *.XML file or the name of it??? Or is it just the actual LOG?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the xml file that the XSLs run against is the entire build log.